# Aspnet_regiis.exe "-norestart" option is not supported under Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis-7.5, aspnet-regiis.exe

I was wondering if there is another option for running the Aspnet_regiis.exe command under Windows Server 2008 R2 such that the IIS worker process is **not restarted**. Microsoft states the  Aspnet_regiis.exe "-norestart" option is not supported under Windows Server 2008. As state here under the -notestart: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Now if we run the command it restarts the process and if users' have session variables set they loose them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the reason the "-norestart" option is not included in 2008 R2 is because it is not needed. Running the command with this server no longer restarts it like it did in previous versions. We ran tests and could see the IIS process memory did not go down after issuing the Aspnet_regiis.exe, nor did we loose session state.